# Most reliable way to generate a timestamp with Python

Tags: python, time

I am wondering what the most reliable way to generate a timestamp is using Python. I want this value to be put into a MySQL database, and for other programming languages and programs to be able to parse this information and use it.

I imagine it is either datetime, or the time module, but I can't figure out which I'd use in this circumstance, nor the method.

Comment: time.time() probably... it returns an int that is easily stored/searched and requires a smaller chunk of memory...

Comment: dates and times are a complicated mess.  what do you want to do with this value?  do you need to do sql queries that include it?  what kinds of queries?  will you need to do things like day of week, or just "before X"?  what resolution do you need?  is a second enough?  do you need to store times before, say, 1970?

Comment: Yea, that looks like the solution that I wanted.

Comment: No, nothing before 1970, I don't think we'll need day of the week, and if we did we'd probably add that functionality later with attaching it to a calendar. Every hour is the resolution needed.

Answer (score 2):

```python
import datetime    
print datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H%M")
```

It should return a string with the format you want. Customize the string by taking a look at [strftime()](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior). This for example is the text format I used for a log filename.

Answer (score 0):

For a database, your best bet is to store it in the database-native format, assuming its precision matches your needs.  For a SQL database, the `DATETIME` type is appropriate.

EDIT: Or `TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: why? an int is smaller and reliably convertible back to a human readable time in pretty much any environment at least as long as second precision is sufficient

Comment: As long as it can support granularity of at least every hour, it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

if it's just a simple timestamp that needs to be read by multiple programs, but which doesn't need to "mean" anything in sql, and you don't care about different timezones for different users or anything like that, then seconds from the unix epoch (start of 1970) is a simple, common standard, and is returned by `time.time()`.

python actually returns a float (at least on linux), but if you only need accuracy to the second store it as an integer.

if you want something that is more meaningful in sql then use a sql type like datetime or timestamp.  that lets you do more "meaningful" queries (like query for a particular day) more easily (you can do them with seconds from epoch too, but it requires messing around with conversions), but it also gets more complicated with timezones and converting into different formats in different languages.